# Ionic list item border not seen

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have created a form using Ionic Creator.
https://creator.ionic.io/share/fdd3f4198103
I am unable to see the borders of select as you can see in my image below.

Source code is :

```html
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-view title="Credentials" id="page9" class=" ">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
        <form id="credentials-form11" class="list ">
            <label class="item item-select " id="credentials-select5">
                <span class="input-label">Select Router</span>
                <select>
                    <option>HData</option>
                    <option>Ajay</option>
                    <option>Test</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <ion-checkbox>Create Hotspot</ion-checkbox>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label " id="credentials-input13">
                <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                <input type="password" placeholder="sample">
            </label>
            <ion-checkbox>Show Password</ion-checkbox>
        </form>
        <div class="list card " id="credentials-card21">
            <ion-item class="item-icon-left dark  " id="credentials-list-item7">
                <i class="icon ion-stats-bars"></i>Progress</ion-item>
            <div style="margin: 0px; line-height: 250px; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(232, 235, 239);">
                <i class="icon ion-image" style="font-size: 64px; color: rgb(136, 136, 136); vertical-align: middle;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="item item-body " id="credentials-list-item-container1">
                <p id="credentials-null" style="margin-top:0px;color:#000000;" class=" ">Some friendly
                    <strong>markdown</strong>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="credentials-button-bar4" class=" button-bar ">
            <button id="credentials-button7" class=" button button-positive  button-block ">Clear</button>
            <button id="credentials-button8" class=" button button-positive  button-block ">Continue</button>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

My output in application is as below.

If anyone could help with the problem of border would be really helpful.
I also applied class for border .itemborder{
  border: 1px solid #4a87ee;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin:10px;
} but its not working.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried placing the border and all other stuff to the select with `.item-select select { border: 1px solid #4a87ee; border-radius: 3px; margin:10px; }`? Because I'm not sure if I'm missing something in your example or what but there's no `itemborder` class in that select?

Comment: Yes i had applied and thats why the output came as per the screenshot. there are no top,bottom borders for first 2 and last label.